# Is a question regarding (a possible bug with) css in IE on-topic for SO?

Tags: discussion

Simplified question:

> W3schools.com renders an example html-page in (in IE 11). I copy the source to notepad and save it as html.
>
> When I open this file in Firefox, everything is okay, but when I open it in IE 11 a specific css property isn't rendered. I compared the source with the original and it is exactly the same, but both pages render differently.

I wanted to ask a question on SO how that could be, but then I realized that the code hasn't changed so I'd reckon it's probably IE's fault.

I don't know if it's a bug, or it's because my settings are wrong (I mean the only difference is that one page is local and the other isn't), but then it seems more logical to post it on a site like SuperUser.

So my question is:
should this be a question for Stack Overflow? Superuser? Or should I got to Area 51 and propose InternetExplorer11.stackexchange.com?

Comment: `should I got to Area 51 and propose InternetExplorer11.stackexchange.com?` I hope you're joking!

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Well if it isn't on-topic for SO or SU, I don't have I choice do I?!??! But no I was kidding ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These kinds of questions are usually on-topic, provided that they contain:

- An understandable problem statement, don't just say it doesn't work, tell us what isn't working
- Minimal code to reproduce the problem
- The expected result

You may want to consider using the following tags as well:

[cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-browser)
[internet-explorer-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-11)
[css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)
and possibly [localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localhost) as the issue seems to appear when you're serving the content from your personal machine.

---

Honestly I see an awful lot of questions of the form:

> Why doesn't this code/property/attribute/etc. work on IE?

I would guess that most of the questions in the internet-explorer tags are variations on that theme, so don't worry you're not alone, nearly everyone who works in web development/design has been tortured by Internet Explorer at some point.

---

On a side note...
I would strongly advise against using w3schools as a reference, see [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) for good reasons not to.

Try [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

CSS questions are within the scope of SO in general. The reason for the difference, in this case, may be because W3 schools uses javascript to make IE able to render that CSS property.

So, if you were to ask a question among the lines of `how can I make this CSS property render properly in IE11`, it would be on-topic AFAIK. Whether or not it is a duplicate is a different matter. Also note that it might not be received well if you don't do your research first. If there are well-known solutions on the internet, you will get downvotes.

Comment: I know that generally CSS is on-topic. But the fact that W3Schools "uses javascript" to populate an Iframe doesn't change the fact that the same source gets rendered correctly while it doesn't if it's local. If I were to ask a question it would be along the line of `why does property X work here, but not when I call it exactly the same way here`

Comment: @Jordy I wasn't referring to the javascript that populates the Iframe, I was referring to javascript that fixes IE11 bugs regarding CSS. "The same source doesn't render correctly if it's local" makes no sense, that's completely impossible. It just can't be the same source then. Anyway I suggest you just post your question.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester, how is it impossible? Different browsers and platforms use different baseline CSS and support different properties and versions of the same. Hence why people use CSS resets to unify the experience across different browsers and platforms.

Comment: @indivisible, I thought your question was about ie11?! This discussion is off-topic for meta. Just post your question on SO and let the votes decide if it's suitable or not.

Comment: It's not my Question but I was just questioning how it would be impossible for CSS display to be different across browsers. The Question appears to be about IE11 in comparison to other browsers. But meh. Like you say, let the community decide and helpful users teak or edit the Question if it seems to need it to bring it in line with SO guidelines.